# extended class has different type than base, supported by interface

Tags: javascript, typescript

Can I write a method which is an extension of a base class, but with a different return type, if it's supported by the shared interface, without inserting type declaration in class 'a'?

In practice classes a & b are in javascript files, and they're failing lint-ts-typing checks.

typescript definition file

```
interface x {
    abc(): string | number;
}
```

javascript file

```
class a implements x {
    abc() {
        return 234;
    }
}

class b extends a implements x {
    abc() {
        return '123';
    }
}
```

throws the following: `Property 'abc' in type 'b' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'a'. Type '() => string' is not assignable to type '() => number'. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.`

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQA9UG9ir6hAIyQAoBKALlQGcIZwBzVAH1TAFcBbQ2AbmAC%20wYEgA2CatQKoQnAA6ionKJCmYc%20AsXLZcm-DCgR2MMKgBMAZgAs-TUKEjxk1IVRR00MABMpCXZpEpGQB%20niGxqaoAOQAjFbRdvgOQA)

Answer (score 2):

TS doesn't force you to implement the interface exactly
You are implementing is as

```
class a implements x {
    abc(): number {
        return 234;
    }
}
```

If you want to keep the `number | string` type, you have to do id expliticly:

```
class a implements x {
    abc(): number | string {
        return 234;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your class **a**, you have to specify the return type of `abc()`. Otherwise it will assume that it only returns number value.
Below code will resolve your error -

```
interface x {
    abc(): string | number;
}

class a implements x {
    abc(): string | number {
        return 234;
    }
}

class b extends a implements x {
    abc() {
        return '123';
    }
}
```